# How write generic interface which maps to properties only with selected types of T?

Tags: typescript, generics

Lets say I have an user object:

```
export class User {

  @Column()
  public email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public birthDate: Date;

  @OneToMany(type => Article, article => article.author)
  public articles: Promise<Article[]>;

}
```

I can create a partial selection with type information with the following interface:

```
export interface Seed<T> {
  rows: {[K in keyof T]?: T[K]}[];
}
```

The problem with this is the following: with this approach I see all relations of the entity so I have to make the key selection of the class partial to accept seeds like:

```
const USER_SEED: Seed<User> = {
  email: test@mail.com,
  name: 'Johny Test',
  birthDate: new Date('1990-01-08'),
}
```

This can cause incorrect seeds where a not nullable field is not provided or a field is provided what is not exists in the table because it's a relation.

My question is how I can create selection of keys with the selected types? In this case I would select keys with the type of string, number and Date

Comment: If a property is nullable why not just mark it as such in the class definition?

Comment: There are fields like `createdAt` or the primary key, which exists all the time, but not needed when seeding the database because it's calculated.

Comment: You can probably have `rows` typed as `Array<Partial<User> & Pick<User, "name" | "email">>` where "name" and "email" are the only non-null properties . But you would have to update non-null columns manually.

Comment: That manual stuff I try to avoid.

Comment: Shouldn't `USER_SEED` be initialized with a `rows` property?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Pick`, which also accepts the key type:

```
Pick<{a: number, b: boolean, c: string}, 'a' | 'b'> ==> {a: number, b: boolean}
```

You can't select keys by their types though.

Comment: Thanks, I know about `Pick`, the problem when a new property is added to the model, nothing will warn at compile time that I have to update my seeds as well, thats why I am looking for an automatic selection of types.

Comment: Things added at runtime cannot be described at compile time. If you want to, you can look at a runtime type system, like MobX state tree.

Comment: It's not added at runtime, I mean if I modify the model, with adding a new column, at recompile it will be visible. However as I research, it seems what I want is only doable via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Split your class into two and apply the Seed to the base one.

```
export abstract class UserFields {

  @Column()
  public email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public birthDate: Date;

}

export class User extends UserFields {

  @OneToMany(type => Article, article => article.author)
  public articles: Promise<Article[]>;

} 

export interface Seed<T> {
  rows: {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}[];
}

const USER_SEED: Seed<UserFields> = {
    rows: [
        {
            email: "test@mail.com",
            name: 'Johny Test',
            birthDate: new Date('1990-01-08')
        }
    ]
}
```